# Finding same element in two array using for loop without any function

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

**I have two array `arr1` and `arr2` I want my output like 1,2,3,4... if my `arr1` and `arr2` contain same number but unfortunately i get only one match**
example if I put `var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]` & `var arr2 = [ 1,2,3,4,5]` then I want my output like:

> > `1,2,3,4,5`

```js
        var i, j;
        var arr1 = new Array(5);
        var arr2 = new Array(5);

        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            arr1[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter The arr1 Element"));
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            arr2[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter The Arr2 Element"));
        }
    
            var k;
            var l;
            for (k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < arr2.length; l++) {
                    if (arr1[k] == arr2[l]) {
                        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = arr1[k];
                       
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Common In Array[]
    </title>
</head>

<body>
   
    <p id="show"></p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Each time the loop goes it prints the value to the innerHTML of the div. But you overwriting it. So if you change = to += it will show your expected output

Comment: Thanks @Rick Bronger Its work well when i replace the `=` to with `+=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> then I want my output like: 1,2,3,4,5

You are only setting one value using *assignment operator* `=`.

```
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = arr1[k];
```

You need to push your values in an array and then show them at once after separating them with `,`

```
var output = [];
for (k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
  for (l = 0; l < arr2.length; l++) {
    if (arr1[k] == arr2[l]) {
      output.push(arr1[k]);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = output.join(",");
```

**Demo**

```js
var i, j;
var arr1 = new Array(5);
var arr2 = new Array(5);

for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  arr1[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter The arr1 Element"));
}

for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  arr2[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter The Arr2 Element"));
}

var k;
var l;
var output = [];
for (k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
  for (l = 0; l < arr2.length; l++) {
    if (arr1[k] == arr2[l]) {
      output.push(arr1[k]);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = output.join(",");
```

```html
<p id="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. You don't need very complex logic to acheive what you want

```js
    var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
    var arr2 = [ 1,2,3,4,5];

    let res = [];

    if(arr1.length >= arr2.length) {
      res = arr1.filter(a => arr2.find(o => o === a));
    } else {
      res = arr2.filter(a => arr1.find(o => o === a));
    }

    console.log(res)
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<p id="show"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var outputstring = "";
for (k = 0; k < arr1.length; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < arr2.length; l++) {
        if (arr1[k] == arr2[l]) {
            outputstring += arr1[k] + ",";
        }
        continue;
    }
}
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = outputstring;
```

Comment: This one also work for me thanks !

Comment: Glad it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter method and compare both arrays...

```js
       
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let arr2 = [1,2,3,6,7];
         
let result = arr1.filter((element)=>arr2.includes(element));   
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
var array2 = [1,2,3,4,5];

var results = array1.filter(function(item) {
    return array2.indexOf(item) !== -1;
});

console.log(results);
```